# SQL Anywhere .NET Data Provider throws Authentication violation exception

Tags: entity-framework, sybase, sqlanywhere

I have a `Sybase` database, from which I generated an `ADO.Net Entity Data Model`. Here's the `connectionString` from the `App.config` file:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Test.csdl|res://*/Test.ssdl|res://*/Test.msl;provider=iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere;provider connection string=&quot;userid=testUser;password=testPassword;datasourcename=test&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

I try to add new entities to a table with a single autoincerement attribute in the database:

```
while (true)
{
    using (var context = new Entities())
    {
        var testEntity = new TestTable();
        context.TestTables.Add(testEntity);
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

which works fine for the first couple (hundred, thousand) iterations. But after that, I get an `iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException` with the message `Authentication violation`, source `"SQL Anywhere .NET Data Provider"`, when callin `context.SaveChanges()`. Here's the stacktrace:

```
at iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SACommand._ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior commandBehavior, Boolean isExecuteScalar, Boolean isBeginExecuteReader)
at iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SACommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
```

I'm using `VS2012`, `.Net Framework v4.5`, `Entity Framework 5.0`, `SQLAnywhere 12 version 12.1.4216`.

Of course this is a simplified scenario, in the real case I'm not calling `SaveChanges()` in a loop, nonetheless I get the same exception after a couple of calls. Any idea to why this exception is thrown and what is the solution would be welcomed.

Comment: Is it ok that user *test* does not have the password?

Comment: When creating the ADO .NET Entity Data Model, you can choose whether to include sensitive data (passwords) or not in the connection string. I've tried both versions, but it seems like I've copied the other one (where password is not included) and the code where I don't provide the password when creating the context. However it's not this what's causing the problem. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the OEM Edition of `SQL Anywhere` can have unauthenticated and  authenticated connections. The unauthenticated ones can only read (in theory) from the database and somehow write to it (for 30 seconds after the first write, in my case the `SaveChanges()` call). Here's the code how to authenticate your connection:

```
private static string AuthCommand = "SET TEMPORARY OPTION CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION='Company=COMPANY_NAME;Application=APPLICATION;Signature=SIGNATURE'";
private bool AuthCommandIssued = false;

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    if (!AuthCommandIssued)
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(AuthCommand);
        AuthCommandIssued = true;
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

More information on this and how to develop authenticated applications and get the authentication parameters can be found [here](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/running-s-4314706.html).